# SpringBootTest - classes - Mock a required constructor argument

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test

We are using SpringBootTest for Integration testing.

Let us say for example that we have a class :
ClassWithManyConstructorArgs with one Required Constructor Argument (another class, DependencyA) and no default constructor.

Example :
public ClassWithManyConstructorArgs(DependencyA a){
}

Our Integration test is configured as :

@SpringBootTest (
classes = [ClassWithManyConstructorArgs::class]
)

I need to provide mocked implementations of the DependencyA class. How can I do that?
What is the syntax to tell the system to initialize the ClassWithManyConstructorArgs using mocked DependencyA object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume we have two beans: ServiceA and ServiceB.

**ServiceA** depends on **ServiceB**. for testing,

1. we load both ServiceA and ServiceB into our test applicationContext(`@SpringBootTest(classes = {ServiceA.class, ServiceB.class})`).
2. use **@InjectMocks** on ServiceA for creating instance that need to be tested, and use **@Mock** on ServiceB for creating mocks that are needed to support the testing.
3. now we can test our methods in ServiceA with the mocked bean serviceB.

here's the code:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ServiceA.class, ServiceB.class})
public class ServiceATest {
  @Mock
  private ServiceB serviceB;

  @InjectMocks
  private ServiceA serviceA;

  @Test
  void testMethodA() {
    serviceA.methodA();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example using three components:

`ComponentToTest`, the component we are going to test. It has two dependencies, one of which we want to mock, and one of which we want to be created normally by Spring.

`ComponentToMock`: we want this replaced by a Mock when `ComponentToTest` is created.

`ComponentNotToMock`: we want the 'real' component to be used.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ComponentToTest {
    private final ComponentToMock componentToMock;
    private final ComponentNotToMock componentNotToMock;


    public ComponentToTest(ComponentToMock componentToMock, ComponentNotToMock componentNotToMock) {
        this.componentToMock = componentToMock;
        this.componentNotToMock = componentNotToMock;
    }

    public String getTheStrings() {
        return componentToMock.getValue() + ", " + componentNotToMock.getValue();
    }
}

package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ComponentToMock {
    public String getValue() {
        return "ComponentToMock not mocked";
    }
}

package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ComponentNotToMock {
    public String getValue() {
        return "ComponentNotToMock not mocked";
    }
}
```

Here's the test:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;


@SpringBootTest()
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
class DemoApplicationTests {
    @MockBean
    ComponentToMock componentToMock;

    @Autowired
    ComponentToTest componentToTest;

    @Test
    void testGetStrings() {
        when(componentToMock.getValue()).thenReturn("This is mocked");
        Assertions.assertEquals("This is mocked, ComponentNotToMock not mocked", componentToTest.getTheStrings());
    }
}
```